# Facebook comments big white block

Tags: facebook, facebook-comments

I'm having an issue with **mobile** facebook comments, I have implemented it with the HTML5 version of the plugin and everything was fine. But now all of the sudden I got a big white background with the height of 1136px. This is coming from a span that Facebook creates before the iframe and inside the iframe and I have now idea why it happened of how to solve it. Any one had the same problem before?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug with the comments plugin right now: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/383938611736678

Try it without a logged in user and it should work. If not, make sure you get the correct code from the plugin page again, including the scheme color:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/

Comment: I forgot to mention that I only see that problem when I visit the site on a mobile device. The code is correct, if you visit with your phone or tablet the developers page you can see the problem as well.

Comment: i think there are many bugs with the comments plugin at the moment, i assume they are in the process of changing some things right now.